# How to bind Command to ParentControl's ViewModel in DataTemplate(bind for ListBox's ItemsTemplate)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

UserControl's DataContext bind to a NotesViewModel(ViewModel) instance which has a ICommand named AddNote, so the ListBox's ContextMenu works.

Now I want to the ContextMenu in the DataTemplate works as ListBox's, how to bind {??????}?

Part of code below:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
    <Border.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="AddNote" Command="{??????}"></MenuItem> <!-- here -->
        </ContextMenu>
    </Border.ContextMenu>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NoteContent}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="noteListBox"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource notesViewSource}}">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem x:Name="AddNoteMenu" 
        Header="AddNote" 
        Command="{Binding AddNote}"/> <!-- here works -->
    </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind using **[x:Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** markup extension.

Set `x:Name` on your listBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox"/>
```

and bind using x:Reference:

```
<MenuItem Header="AddNote" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddNote,
                                             Source={x:Reference myListBox}}"/>
```

**PS** - Please not binding with `ElementName` won't work because ContextMenu doesn't lie in same Visual Tree as that of ListBox. Hence, we need to use `x:Reference` here.

Comment: @san - You're welcome san. Welcome to SO and accept it as an answer. [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).